# Simulate Split View Controller's Display Mode Button Item in Code

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, swift

Split View Controllers provide a Display Mode Button Item like such:

[image]

Which hides the master view and expands the detail view.

My question is, is there a way to simulate this button's action in code?

Comment: Changing displayMode (or preferredDisplayMode) changes the display without animation. I'd like it to be animated.

Comment: samequestion here. Did you find a answer?

Comment: I ended up not needing this, so no...but I assume putting `setPreferredDisplayMode` in an animation block would do it.

Comment: Same here. I turned out not using UISplitViewController at all. Instead, AMSlideMenu had just the flexibility I need. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Likewise, i too was looking for an answer to this question. And sadly not much was to be found regarding this.**

A simple way is to use the `UISplitViewController Delegate:`

```
-(UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode)targetDisplayModeForActionInSplitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc{
```

To Create our desired button and handle the action with a `@Selector`

> The code below may be helpful:

```
-(UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode)targetDisplayModeForActionInSplitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc{
if (svc.displayMode == UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden) {
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showMenu)];
}else{
    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight || [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    }
}
return UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAutomatic;
}
```

**Whats Happening?**

- First, we check for the `displayMode` whether it is `PrimaryHidden` or `AllVisible` and based on that we customise our navigation button.
- Then below that we check for the device orientation so that the default `DisplayMode` button can be nilled.

> Then the selector method for our button can be like:

```
-(void)showMenu{

if ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight || [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
    if (self.splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode == UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden) {
        self.splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible;
    } else {
        self.splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden;
    }
}
else{
    self.splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay;
}

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^ {
    [self.splitViewController.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
}
```

The `UIView animation` was added to make it look as like apple's animation.